# What does [`something] some_vector ; mean in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

Let's say I have some define macro, and then some other wire that is defined. 

 What does it mean when I have them like this? Is it just meaning to take the 2 LSBs from the wire?

```
`define A_DEFINE  32
// *SOME CODE IN HERE*
output  [`A_DEFINE-1:0] my_out_wire;
// *MORE CODE HERE*
```

I can't seem to find any explanation of this meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `` `define A_DEFINE 32 `` declares a macro called `A_DEFINE`. A macro is a thing you can use for text replacement in your code.

The syntax `` `A_DEFINE `` means expand the `A_DEFINE` macro. This is essentially taking the value of `A_DEFINE` and copying in the place where the macro is expanded.

The preprocessor does this for you. In essence, you'll end up with:

```
// *SOME CODE IN HERE*
output  [32-1:0] my_out_wire;
// *MORE CODE HERE*
```

Defines are handy if you need to have a configurable element in your code. This way if you have multiple signals that are supposed to be as wide, you just use the define. In case you need to change from 32 to 64, you just modify the define and that's it.

Also have a look at the SystemVerilog `parameter`. This might also be helpful.

Comment: Thank's a bunch; One more question though, will this set my_out_wire to 31 downto 0 and paste A_DEFINE's value into the vector? Or will it be 32 downto 0 with A_DEFINE as the upper part?

Comment: @user54590 It does text replacement so you will have  `output  [32-1:0] my_out_wire;` which is a 32 bit wire with elements 31 to 0.

Comment: Thanks Morgan! That helps me out more than you know!